# Redmine: Add built-in field to Ticket

Tags: field, redmine, issue-tracking

How do I add a built-in field like "Target Version" to the "new issue" form in Redmine?

I can choose which custom fields should be used on the project's configuration page, but where is the option to configure which default-fields to be used?

Using Redmine v.2.5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard fields' usage is linked to trackers. You have first to select the standard fields that you want to be used in specific trackers.

- Go to "Administration"
- Go to "Trackers"
- Select the tracker that you want to customize
- Select the standard fields that you want to use in that tracker

Then you have to define the permissions for these fields.

- Go to "Administration".
- Go to "Workflow"
- Open the "Workflow" for that specific tracker by selecting the tracker and role and then pressing the "Edit" button. (if you want to specify this for all trackers then you'll have to do this for each tracker separately)
- Switch to "Fields Permissions" tab
  You'll have to select the field permissions according to their statuses in this matrix. For example if you want to restrict the user to not being able to select a project when entering a new task, you should select "read only" in the box where the "project" line and the "new" columns are crossing.
  If you select "Required" for fields, those fields will be forced to the user as mandatory fields.

Comment: Thank you. So, there is no way to have different field definitions for one tracker for different projects?
I would have to create seperate (i.e. "Improvement")-Trackers for each project to use different fields?

Comment: Yes and that's real life's projection. What you're planning would be a too granular customization and wouldn't reflect the real situation.

To achieve your goal you can select all the standard fields for all trackers and then limit them in "Fields Permissions" by selecting the unwanted fields as "read-only" so they wouldn't be selectable during task entry.